# What is the purpose of using C29 and R13?

Tags: power-electronics

What is the purpose of using C29 and R13?

[image]

Comment: Some kind of "snubber". What is the load of Q5?

Comment: No idea. Could you zoom out to show the whole schematic?

Comment: @Antonio51 Load of Q5 is BLDC motor

Comment: Show the full circuit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an RC snubber.

It catches and reduces overshoots and undershoots and prevents ringing of fast edges which would otherwise stress or damage components and cause conducted and radiated electromagnetic interference.